# What happens to String variable in Java when the value is changed?

Tags: java

which is correct

According to "Murachs Java programming" when you assign a new value to a string variable the original string object is deleted and its replaced by a new String object.

But according to my professor the object stays in string constant pool only the reference variable now points to a new memory location of the newly assigned value.

Comment: Neither of those descriptions is completely correct.

Comment: Please cite *exactly* what the Murach book or whatever it is actually says.

Comment: @EJP when you assign a new value to a string variable, the original string abject is deleted and its replaced with a new String object that contains the new value<Murachs

Comment: Dear members, any reason for so many down votes ?

Comment: First: why don't you ask your professor? Second: What research have you done to find the answer prior asking here?

Comment: I don't see any reason why SO should become a validation site for other people's random statements. It could silt up in no time.

Comment: Actually, I suspect that part of the problem is that you are not *accurately* relaying what the book or your professor actually say.

Comment: @StephenC Thats exactly what the book says, the part I replied to EJP. thats on page 424 1st para. Murachs java programming 4th edition.I guess they didnt do a proper technical review of it.

Answer (score 3):

Neither is correct.

1. The quotation from the Murach book is wrong. The object referenced by the previous value is *dereferenced,* and becomes *eligible* for garbage collection when there are no more references to it. This may or may not ever happen. There is certainly no question of it being immediately deleted or replaced by the new object.
2. Your professor is also wrong, except in the specific cases of string literals, compile-time string expressions, and `String` objects that have been interned.

Comment: Oh sorry that's what my professor meant...It stays in the SCP and later becomes eligible for garbage collection when there are no more references pointing towards it.Lesson learnt ..official books can also be wrong sometimes.

Comment: @DePaul That's still wrong. Strings only go *into* the constant pool under the condtions I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

> According to "Murachs Java programming" when you assign a new value to a string variable the original string object is deleted and its replaced by a new String object.

This is incorrect.  Assignment to String variable does not cause anything to be deleted, and does not cause the creation of a new String object.  That applies to all assignments.  Indeed, *no action in Java* can be said to cause the deletion of an object.  The best you can say is that an assignment *may* cause an object to become unreachable, and an unreachable object will eventually become unreachable.

> But according to my professor the object stays in string constant pool only the reference variable now points to a new memory location of the newly assigned value.

That is closer, but it is also incorrect in a couple of important respects:

1. Most String objects are not created in the string pool in the first place, and don't ever go there.  A regular `String` is created in the regular heap (NOT the string pool<sup>*</sup>).  The only way for user code to create an object in the string pool is to call `String.intern()` ... which will (if necessary) allocate and return an object in the string pool.

   The String objects that represent string *literals* at runtime do live in the string pool.  However, user code doesn't create them.  Rather, they are typically<sup>**</sup> created in the string pool the first time that a method that uses the literal are used.
2. The newly assigned String reference does not necessarily refer to a new memory location.  It could point to an object created a long time ago.

---

<sup>* - In old versions of Java, the string pool was held in a special heap called the "permgen" heap which had a different garbage collection policy associated with it.  In current versions, "permgen" no longer exists and the string pool is simply a data structure in the main heap.</sup>

<sup>** - Again, this is Java version specific.  The insertion of a string literal into the sting pool *could* occur earlier; e.g. when the class is loaded.</sup>